# How do I check if a list contains at least one sublist?

Tags: python, list, set, subset, sublist

I have two lists. One which has 10 lots of 3 objects(so calling as `list[0]`, shows the 3 objects withing [0]). I then have another List that has a certain number of objects (it will be changing but we can use 6 objects as an example).

I need to create a loop which tests the 6 objects against the 10 lots of 3 (So, `list[0]`, `list[1]`... etc) and if at any point the list of 6 has 3 objects which match to one of the 10 mini lists, it will `Return True`.

As an example too:

`6_ObjList = [A,B,D,H,G]`

`3_ObjList[0] = [A,D,J]` - Should not return true and keep looping

`3_ObjList[1] = [A,D,H]` - Should return true and break the loop

If none match - `Return False`. Sorry if that is all jumbled up and makes no sense.
This is kind of what I was thinking.

```
    for i in range(0,10):
        if(6_ObjList.Contains(3_ObjList[i])):
            return True
    return False
```

Comment: In python, variable name cannot start from a number

Answer (score 1):

If I've correctly interpreted your question, you mean:

> How can I find out whether one of the sublists of a nested list contains only items that are in another, separate list.

In that case, you want something like:

```
>>> lst_of_lst = [[1, 3, 7], [2, 4, 6], [0, 1, 2]]
>>> lst = [0, 1, 2, 3]
>>> any(all(item in lst for item in sub_lst) for sub_lst in lst_of_lst)
True
```

Comment: Thanks for the fast response!!! I tried it out and I got no errors however it did respond false, where it should return true. 
I can't really think of a reason for this, apart from maybe because my version of your 1st_of_1st isn't in order like yours is? and also since they are objects vs ints? I am not actually sure why I am getting false

Comment: @NickoM without a [minimal example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), it's impossible to say. Note that integers **are** objects.

Comment: Sorry I am new to this and found it hard to attach that, here is a picture of the code http://puu.sh/hKz6D/b3b6ad30f6.png #EDITED LINK if you can't see that I can try type it out

Comment: @NickoM *picture of the code*!? Do me a favour... Please **edit the question** to give a minimal **text** example, per the link I just posted and the [editing guidance](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help).

Comment: Never mind, I figured out what was wrong, my list, similar to your "1st" list, was essentially 1st = [[0,1,2,3]] so it wasn't actually testing the actual list.
Thanks for your help

Comment: Using this method, is there any way to know which of the sublists has caused True, to then be selected and added somewhere else?

Comment: @NickoM no - if that matters, split it out into a loop rather than using `any` (i.e. `for sub_lst in lst_of_lst: if all(...): ...`)

Answer (score 1):

if your items are unique, the perfomant way of doing this is by using sets:

```
list6 = set(['A', 'B', 'D', 'H', 'G'])
list10 = [set(['A', 'D', 'J']),
          set(['A', 'D', 'H'])]

def myfunc():
    for i in list10:
        if i.issubset(list6):
            return True
    return False
```

Answer (score -4):

```
for i in 6_ObjList:
    for j in 3_ObjList:
        if i == j:
            return True
        else:
            return False
```

Comment: In python, variable name cannot start with a digit

Comment: To be fair, the invalid variable names are probable taken over from the original question. Nevertheless, please add some explanation to your code (and edit it to be syntactically correct) to improve this answer a bit.